# Which hero gets a "Game Won" in the statistics if I switch heroes mid-game?

Tags: overwatch

In Overwatch, you can view a number of statistics on various heroes you've played throughout the game. One of the notable ones to look at is "Games Won".

One might think that if you play a game and use a hero, you've played one game as that hero, and if you win that game, it should count towards your "games won" for that hero.

But Overwatch is also a game where you can change heroes halfway through a game - starting as one, then changing if things go poorly or if the situation calls for it.

So if I start a game as one hero, then finish it as another, and win, how does the game count how many "Games Won" to add to which heroes?

To clarify: On the "Overview" page, if I select "games won" in the "Hero comparison", if I use several heroes during a single game, which hero(s) "games won" would increase?

Comment: Title is somewhat broad for this specific question. Maybe something like "Which hero's statistics shows 'Game won' if I use several heroes during a game?"

Comment: @OrcJMR Not quite what I'm asking, but close - I'll try to clarify in the question itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the end of a match, character win/loss statistics are attributed *as a fraction* corresponding to the percentage of the match's duration played as that character. On the character statistics display, however, character wins/losses are rounded to the nearest integer, which is responsible for much of the confusion surrounding the statistic.

As stated by [Scott Mercer on the Battle.net forums](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20745114851?page=1#post-5):

> When you get a win, each hero is credited for a portion of the win corresponding to the % of the match's playtime as that hero.
>
> So if you play Mercy 60% of a match you won, and Lucio 40% of that same match, the hero specific win totals on the career overview are credited by 0.6 and 0.4, respectively. We then round the displayed value of games won by hero to the nearest integer.

In Scott's example, assuming 0 wins for both Mercy and Lucio prior to the match, the character statistics would display 1 win for Mercy and 0 for Lucio. The next time a match was won with at least 10% of the game spent playing Lucio, he too would display a win.

Answer (score 2):

The game calculates wins based on what hero you *finish* the map, as far as my experience goes. In beta, it also seemed to mark all played characters that game as having lost if you didn't win, but I'm not sure if that's still the case.

When I get home later, I'll record my "games won" and "games lost" for a couple of heroes before and after quick play, then update this answer with my findings for some (hopefully) more conclusive evidence to support.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: I'll use a recent example as a counter argument to this: I just recently played a game in volskaya where we were pushed back extremely fast - I was playing widow at that point. On the last push of the payload, I changed to bastion (a character I only played to a loss that day) and we procceeded to defend and win the game. However, my statistics counted a win for widow, and still only had the one loss for bastion.

Comment: @fcm Payload on Volskaya? :P One of those is inconsistent with the other.  Perhaps Dorado? (Only map I can think of with strong last point Bastion hideyholes)

Comment: oops, confused the maps, I meant numbani - volskaya was the one I actually lost as bastion.

Comment: @fcm Gotcha. This might complicate things then. Did you spend more time on Widow than you did on Bastion? If so, I may need to check if it's based on "most used hero" for that game. So if you played 11 minutes as Zarya, then swapped to Tracer to get back to the point, but you won before getting there, that it would count as a Zarya win.

Comment: @KizTrap I definitely played more Bastion than Widow that map, they capped and moved the payload to the final point very fast, and I changed at the last point, where we stood for the remaining 8 or so minutes of the game.

Comment: @fcm Interesting. I keep forgetting to hero swap mid game in order to test this, should probably like, set a reminder on my phone or something

Comment: I just tested a Lijiang tower map- Started as Pharah for round 1, rounds 2 and 3 were Genji. Spent longer on Genji, and my wins went from 58 to 59.  What are you using to track these stats? I'm using the ingame Overview